# Problem with "for" loop and "command" arg of CTkOptionMenu

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

Well, I have a nested dictionary:

```py
d = {'id': {'a': CTkButton(), 'b': CTkButton(), 'c': CtkOptionMenu()},
     'id': {'a': CTkButton(), 'b': CTkButton(), 'c': CtkOptionMenu()}
     ...
    }
```

where id is:

- row index
- key of other global dict
- etc.

I need to put this index to

```py
def lexicon_callback(choice, k):
```

function (second arg). As you might guess, I create this dict through a loop. So I write this:

```py
for key in var.old_lang.keys():
    # here is some code
    self.lang_dictionary_edit_entities[key]['lex'] = customtkinter.CTkOptionMenu(
                    self.lang_dictionary_edit_frame, height=100,
                    values=list(var.lexicon.keys()), command=lambda choice: 
                    lexicon_callback(choice, key)
                )
```

The problem is that no matter what option menu I use, lambda function always put the last key ("41" in my case) in the "k" variable of lexicon_callback. I can understand why, but don't know, what to do with this situation.